# Why does this infinite sum of functions converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $0 < \alpha_1 < \alpha_2 < \cdots $ be and suppose that $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{\alpha_i} < \infty.$$ Let us now for each $n \geq 0,$ define the function
$$s_n(z) = \sum_{i=1}^n |\dfrac{2z+2}{2+\alpha_n+z}|$$ where $z \in \mathbb{C}.$

Under these assumptions, why does it follow that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n$$ converges uniformly to a function on any compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$ not containing any of the points $-2-\alpha_n?$

Comment: Should it be $\alpha_i$ in the definition of $s_n(z)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be the compact set, and let $M>0$ satisfy $|x|<M$ for all $x\in X$.

Choose $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\alpha_i>2M+4$ for $i>N$.

Then $|2z+2|<2M+2$ and $|2+\alpha_i+z|\geq \alpha_i-|2|-|z|>\alpha_i/2$ for $i>N$.

So ${\displaystyle 
\sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty} \left|\frac{2z+2}{2+\alpha_i+z}\right|
\leq
\sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty} \frac{4M+4}{\alpha_i}
}$
is a bound independent of $z$.